# Git with Wordpress - gitignore deleting plugins when switching branches?

Tags: html, wordpress, git

I am using git to manage a Wordpress project. In my `.gitignore`, I am 'ignoring' the `wp/wp-content/plugins` directory to avoid having them as part of the repository. However, the problem is, every time I create a new branch, merge it back into the master and switch back to master, the `plugins` directory disappears!

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

The relevant sections of the `.gitignore`:

```
wp/wp-content/*
!wp/wp-content/plugins/
wp/wp-content/plugins/*
```

Shouldn't it just leave anything in the plugins directory alone?

Note: I based my `.gitignore` on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/444295)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vanishing file included in .gitignore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606974/vanishing-file-included-in-gitignore)